# passing dynamically generated varchar string to 'IN' clause of select statement of oracle sql anonymous block is not returning any value

Tags: sql, oracle11g

I am passing dynamically generated varchar to IN clause of select statement in oracle SQL, its not giving any error or any output. 
query-->

```
select name from name_master where name in(generated_string);
```

here , generated_string is like 'A','B','C','D'

when I use the generated_string(copy pasting after using put_line in anonymous block) inside other separate query, its giving me the name column output. 
running below query works fine.

```
select name from name_master where name in('A','B','C','D');
```

any suggestions are welcome. 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: most probably the single quote needs to be handled in order no to be treated as special character ... adding a slash r something like that

Comment: You can use Dynamic SQL for this: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B10501_01/appdev.920/a97269/pc_13dyn.htm

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
select name from name_master where name in (SELECT   COLUMN_VALUE
                          FROM   table (split (generated_string, ','))
```

If split function is not there in your database you can create using below query.

```
FUNCTION split (p_list VARCHAR2, p_del VARCHAR2)
   RETURN split_tbl
IS
   l_idx    NUMBER (8);
   v_i      NUMBER (8)       := 0;
   l_list   VARCHAR2 (32767) := p_list;
   l_data   split_tbl        := split_tbl ();
BEGIN
   LOOP
      l_idx := INSTR (l_list, p_del);

      IF l_idx > 0
      THEN
         l_data.EXTEND;
         l_data (l_data.COUNT) := SUBSTR (l_list, 0, l_idx - 1);
         l_list := SUBSTR (l_list, l_idx + LENGTH (p_del));
      ELSE
         l_data.EXTEND;
         l_data (l_data.COUNT) := l_list;
         EXIT;
      END IF;
   END LOOP;
   RETURN l_data;

-- the split_tbl object as currently defined is a varray of 200 (max) elements
-- this exception handler should let the split_tbl get to its capacity..
-- depending on the use of this function, we may need to increase the size of
-- split_tbl to hold more elements..
EXCEPTION WHEN SUBSCRIPT_OUTSIDE_LIMIT THEN
   RETURN l_data;


END SPLIT;
```